# How do I add a image logo to the top nav bar in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll

Just started using Jekyll to generate some basic pages and wanted to add a image logo to the top branding area on the navigation bar. Is there a standard way to do this without messing with the themes in Jekyll?

Comment: You mention themes, are you using [Jekyll-Bootstrap](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/)?

Comment: Yes I am. Just the default one that comes with jekyllbootstrap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to do this without at least a little customizing of the theme.

However, since you're using the default, twitter theme for Jekyll-Bootstrap, these changes should be fairly straightforward to make:

Put your logo.png in `assets/themes/twitter`

In your `_includes/themes/twitter/default.html` you'll want to add a `<li>` with your logo under the `<ul class="nav">` element like so:

```
<li><a class="brand-image" href="{{ HOME_PATH }}"><img class="brand-image" src="{{ASSET_PATH}}/logo.png"/></a></li>
```

Next, define the `brand-image` class by editing `assets/themes/twitter/css/style.css` and add the following:

```
.navbar .nav > li > a.brand-image {
      padding: 4px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.navbar .nav > li > a > img.brand-image {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
       -moz-border-radius: 0px;
            border-radius: 0px;
```

}

You'll probably have to play with the padding to get it to work just right for your image.